# Open iOS 6 native map from URL passing address string @ given coordinates

Tags: maps, ios6, url-scheme

Prior to iOS 6 you could open the map app passing a destination address using this URL:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/?daddr=Tom's%20House@40.70,-74.10
```

Note the address format: **mystring@latitude,longitude**

Where you basically tell the app to place the marker at the given coordinates and show "mystring" in the address field.

With iOS 6 they changed the host from maps.google.com to maps.apple.com, but now the above address format does not work anymore:

```
http://maps.apple.com/maps/?daddr=Tom's%20House@40.70,-74.10
```

As daddr you can pass EITHER a real address OR just the coordinates but, apparently, not both.

The Apple docs about this: [Apple URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1) are not very helpful as they contain no mention of how saddr and daddr fields can be formatted.

Does anybody know if this format/behavior is still supported somehow?

Comment: Under iOS 6, you may want to try MKMapItem and its openMapsWithItems:launchOptions: method instead.

Comment: @anna this would work from a native app. I'm trying to do it using a link/URL inside a webpage (i.e.: from Safari)